# JDBCTemplate can't handle to_date(). it gives an exception: Invalid column name

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a microservice spring boot 2 application, using JDBCTemplate to get the data from Oracle database.

I tried the following SQL code:

```
String query = "select * from usiis.vw_patients where first_name=? and last_name=? and dob =  to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')";
```

but I keep getting **'java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name'** error.
I tried the same code on SQLDeveloper and it worked fine:

```
select * from usiis.vw_patients where first_name='BRINLEE' and last_name='DENNEY' and dob=TO_DATE('1998-06-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

then I removed [and dob =  to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')"] from the query string in my application the query worked fine too:
String query = "select * from usiis.vw_patients where first_name=? and last_name=?

so I figured the issue is the JDBCTemplate can't handle to_date() function properly.

it is hard to believe that I couldn't find a solution for an important issue like this in spring boot. I tried googling it for a long time and couldn't find a similar issue.
can anyone help please...

Spring boot: 2.0.2.RELEASE
Java: 1.8
Oracle.jdbc7: 12.1.0
Oracle: 12.1.x

EX:

```
...
String query = "select * from usiis.vw_patients where first_name=? and last_name=? and dob =  to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')";
Object[] queryArgsObj = usiisDBAccessPatientURI.getQueryArgsObj();
List<Common_UsiisReturnedRow> usiisReturnedRows = oracleTemplate.query
                  (query,
                   queryArgsObj,
                   new UsiisRowMapper());
```

Usiis DBAccess...queryArgsObj: **BRINLEE**
Usiis DBAccess...queryArgsObj: **DENNEY**
Usiis DBAccess...queryArgsObj: **1998-06-13**

```
class UsiisRowMapper implements RowMapper<Common_UsiisReturnedRow>
    {
        @Override
        public Common_UsiisReturnedRow mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            Common_UsiisReturnedRow usiisRetRow = new Common_UsiisReturnedRow();

            usiisRetRow.setFirst_name( (rs.getString("first_name")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setLast_name( (rs.getString("last_name")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setDob( rs.getDate("dob") );
            usiisRetRow.setGender( (rs.getString("gender")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setEth_code( (rs.getString("eth_code")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setAddress_street( (rs.getString("address_street")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setAddress_city( (rs.getString("address_city")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setAddress_state( (rs.getString("address_state")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setAddress_zip( (rs.getString("address_zip")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setPhone_number( (rs.getString("phone_number")).trim() );           
            usiisRetRow.setVaccine_id( (rs.getInt("vaccine_id")) );
            usiisRetRow.setVaccine_code( (rs.getInt("vaccine_code")) );
            usiisRetRow.setVaccine_name( (rs.getString("vaccine_name")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setVaccination_date( (rs.getString("vaccination_date")).trim() );
            usiisRetRow.setDose_no( (rs.getInt("dose_no")) );

            return usiisRetRow;
        }           
    }
```

I should get at least one patient row but instead I get:

2019-05-20 10:05:06.706 ERROR 7876 --- [nio-4007-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from usiis.vw_patients where first_name=? and last_name=? and dob =  to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3965) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:299) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:1350) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but would it be okay to do the string-to-date conversion in Java and then just have `dob = ?` in the query?

Comment: The error occurs on an `rs.getInt` call. I don't see how that could be correlated with using `to_date` or not. Please post a [mcve] and the **full** exception stacktrace.

Comment: how date is stored in your database? Varchar2 or date ?

Comment: doing the string-to-date conversion is a good way to solve this issue temporarily.

Comment: the column is defined as a DATE datatype in the database.

Comment: this is the first time I submitted an issue here. sorry I did not post the full exception stacktrace. I do not own the view and I requested to change the dob/date column to a varchar2 to resolve this issue quickly while I find a solution to the to_date() problem. I'll need sometime to revert this change back to the original state before I'll be able to get the full stacktrace again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just re-downloaded oracle jdbc7 jar file again and it worked. thank you all for looking at this issue with me.
actually, I was worried that in jdbc7 combined with JDBCTemplate oracle functions don't work. I am so glad this was not the case.